Angular Switch with multiple types
I used to make this trick in my latest projects which was
  results = signal<
    | { state: 'error'; error: string }
    | { state: 'normal' }
    | { state: 'success'; message: string }
    | { state: 'loading' }
  >({ state: 'normal' });

giving results multiple types. and in HTML
@switch (results().state) {
  @case ("error") {
    <div role="alert" class="alert alert-error">
      <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        class="h-6 w-6 shrink-0 stroke-current"
        fill="none"
        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      >
        <path
          stroke-linecap="round"
          stroke-linejoin="round"
          stroke-width="2"
          d="M10 14l2-2m0 0l2-2m-2 2l-2-2m2 2l2 2m7-2a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z"
        />
      </svg>
      <span>{{ results().error }}</span>
    </div>
  }
}

which worked fine before, However in my latest project it says

Property 'error' does not exist on type '{ state: "error"; error:
string; } | { state: "normal"; } | { state: "success"; message:
string; } | { state: "loading"; }'.   Property 'error' does not exist
on type '{ state: "normal"; }'

Is there any settings I should tweek to make it work again?

Use @let and do the following instead:
@let r = results();
@switch (r.state) {
  @case ("error") {
    <div role="alert" class="alert alert-error">
      <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        class="h-6 w-6 shrink-0 stroke-current"
        fill="none"
        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      >
        <path
          stroke-linecap="round"
          stroke-linejoin="round"
          stroke-width="2"
          d="M10 14l2-2m0 0l2-2m-2 2l-2-2m2 2l2 2m7-2a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z"
        />
      </svg>
      <span>{{ r.error }}</span>
    </div>
  }
}

The idea is to call results() once and determine its type. Calling again raises the possibility that it is not of type error

Stackblitz Demo

Thank you so much for the fast replay, I have upgraded to angular 18 and your solution works perfect

@MahmoudEl-Yamani you are welcome. Would appreciate if you confirm my answer.

off course, i did it
